# stomp-chat web socket with embedded tomcat reactor error - type reactor.tuple.Tuple not found

Tags: websocket, spring-integration, project-reactor

I am having problems getting web socket subscriptions to work properly using Spring with an embedded Tomcat server.

When running this [stomp-chat application](https://github.com/artembilan/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/stomp-chat) I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: @chatRoomSessions[headers.simpDestination].add(T(reactor.tuple.Tuple).of(headers.simpSessionId, headers.simpSubscriptionId));
nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 58): Type cannot be found 'reactor.tuple.Tuple'
```

I tried to add the following dependency:

```
compile ("io.projectreactor:reactor-stream:$reactorVersion")
```

but it gave the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I see the problem.

The dependency for the `io.projectreactor:reactor-stream:2.0.8` isn't enough.

The `Tuple` class has been moved to the new `reactor.fn.tuple` package.

So, you still have to fix all the `reactor.tuple.Tuple` mentioning in the `stomp-server.xml` to the new `reactor.fn.tuple.Tuple`.

The sample will be fixed soon: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/issues/185

Sorry for inconvenience.